# JS/ES6: Check if every array element has a child in another array

Tags: javascript, arrays

There are three object arrays like this:

```
sections = [{ _id: '123'}]
groups   = [{ _id: '456', parent: '123' }]
items    = [{ _id: '789', parent: '456' }]
```

This is a valid dataset. Of course there are multiple objects in the arrays.

Now I want to check if every section has a minimum of one child group and every group have minimum one item.
If this check fails, `false` value should be returned.

**Example**

```
sections = [{ _id: '123'}]
groups   = [{ _id: '456', parent: '123' }]
items    = [{ _id: '789', parent: 'something' }]

complete = false
```

In this example false should be returned, as there is no child item for the group.

I tried to start with a forEach-loop, but this is a wrong attempt:

```
let complete = true
sections.forEach(s => {
    if (groups.filter(g => { return g.parent === s._id }).length === 0)
        complete = false
})
```

Comment: is it correct to say that `section` is the parent of `groups` and `groups` is the parent of `items`?  And that you expect each `section` to have their id registered as a parent property of one or more `groups` and so on for groups -> items?  otherwise, it is incomplete?

Comment: yes, thats correct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you have a three arrays. Two contain objects that serve as parent elements, and two contain objects that serve as child elements. You want to check whether every parent in the list of parents has a defined child.

This functionality can be achieved using a helper function `everyParentHasChild(parents, children)`, which is built on the higher-level array methods `Array#every` and `Array#some`.

```js
let sections = [{ _id: '123'}]
let groups   = [{ _id: '456', parent: '123' }]
let items    = [{ _id: '789', parent: '456' }]

let everyParentHasChild = (parents, children) => parents.every(
  parent => children.some(child => child.parent === parent._id)
)

let result = everyParentHasChild(sections, groups) && everyParentHasChild(groups, items)

console.log(result) //=> true
```

Comment: Nice work. You posted the same solution as me (helper function and all) ten seconds before I did. I'll delete mine.

Comment: Agreed; I really like this answer.  I proposed another solution, but this is much more elegant

Comment: Thanks for the support :) I love these new array functions and I can't wait until ES6 features will be fair game for all SO questions due to overwhelming browser support.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const sections = [{ _id: '123'}];
const groups   = [{ _id: '456', parent: '123' }];
const items    = [{ _id: '789', parent: 'something' }];

const isComplete = function() {
  // check sections 
  for (const section of sections) {
    if (!groups.filter(group => group.parent == section._id).length) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  // check groups
  for (const group of groups) {
    if (!items.filter(item => item.parent == group._id).length) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
};

console.log(isComplete());
```